# Remover pergunta destaque aparentemente abandonada e de baixa qualidade

Tags: debate

O que acham dessa pergunta?
[JSON para PHP via AJAX](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78004/json-para-php-via-ajax)

Essa pergunta está começando a criar mofo.

Na minha opinião, também tem baixa qualidade. Falta mais informações, o feedback do AP é fraco ou nulo.

O pessoal que responde pede por feedback e o AP praticamente ignora ou não dá um retorno adequado. É tudo sempre muito vago e desleixado.

Nesse tipo de situação, não poderia remover do destaque?

Comment: Ela vai sumir sozinha durante a noite, a recompensa já expirou.

Comment: @bfavaretto acho que a pergunta do Daniel é se uma pergunta, mesmo que com recompensa, se não deveria ser retirada do destaque por ser de fraca qualidade. É isso Daniel?

Comment: exato, Jorge, no entanto, acho que o bfavaretto entendeu mas como a pergunta já sairia fora do destaque automaticamente, então foi mais conveniente deixar quieto. t

Comment: O problema de tirar do destaque é que a pessoa "pagou" exatamente pelo destaque com seus pontos. O fato de alguém poder ganhar o bônus depois é um mero desdobramento.

Comment: Acho que o fato de pagar com os pontos que possui é irrelevante. Afinal pagou para ter o destaque de algo fora de escopo ou passível de fechamento. Fazendo uma analogia: Você obtém licensas da prefeitura para fazer uma apresentação numa praça pública e obviamente pagou taxas. Então na apresentação comete certas contravenções, faz piadas racistas ou alguém aparece nú (apenas exemplo). Imediatamente, a polícia vai pedir para que se retire, independente se pagou ou não. O fato de pagar pelo espaço não dá o direito de infrigir normas. Dá direito ao espaço, mas ainda deve cumprir as normas.

Comment: inverteram a duplicata... achei que a mais antiga deveria ter prioridade..